# mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Nenhuma conex�o p�de ser feita porque a m�quina de destino as recusou ativamente

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, mysqli, phpmyadmin

[image: Erro]

Estou com um problema para acessar meu phpMyAdmin. Comecei a utilizar o WampServer para programar em PHP. Não sei se devo fazer alguma configuração inicial, porém a forma que tentei logar foi sem preencher Utilizador e Palavra-passe, ou só colocando root em Utilizador e Palavra-passe em branco, mas esse erro sempre aparece. Já chequei o config.inc.php dentro de C:\WampServer\apps\phpmyadmin4.8.5 e aparece isso:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

Comment: resolvir meu problema indo no mysql installer indo nessa opção e adcionando uma senha pro phpmyadmin Root
senha

Answer (score 1):

Sua porta esta bloqueada ou não esta com o padrão. Faça o seguinte:

1. Verifique se o Mysql esta sendo executado.
2. Verifique a porta do mysql esta na padrão 3306
   O 1 e 2 você consegue verificar clicando no ícone do WampServer próximo ao relógio do Windows

[image: WampServer]

3. Verifique bloqueio do firewall.
   Desative **temporariamente** para teste o(s) firewall que você estiver utilizando inclusive o do Windows.
4. Altere a porta no config.inc.php do phpmyadmin se a porta do mysql não estiver a padrão 3306.
   Basta abrir o arquivo com um editor de texto simples, notepad, notepad++, vscode, e altera a porta pela porta utilizada pelo mysql.
   [Link documentação, alteração de porta](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/pt_BR/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_port)